# Retrieving a JSON Response in a blade view - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel

I want to do a bill structure where I can choose a client and the next select form will show me all the items of the client, but for some reason I'm having troubles with that.

This is my route.php

```
Route::resource('bills', 'BillsController');
Route::get('bills/items','BillsController@items');
```

And this is my BillsController

```
private function items($request) {
    try {
        if ($request) {
            $id = $request->client_id;
            $items = Item::where('client_id', $id)->get()->pluck('code', 'id');

            return redirect()->json($items);
        } else {
            \Session::flash('error_message', 'Ups! Hemos tenido un error.');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        \Session::flash('error_message', 'Ups! Hemos tenido un error.');
            return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

And this is the script in my blade view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#clients').change(function() {
        var $client_id = $('#clients').val();
        console.log($client_id);
        var $url = '{{ url('MyAdmin/bills/items') }}';
        console.log($url);
        $.getJSON($url, {'client_id': $client_id}, function(resp) {
            console.log(resp); //For some reason here the "resp" is not working
            $.each(resp, function(key, answer) {
                $('#items').append('<option value="'+answer.id+'">'+answer.code+'</option>');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That is because it's actually getting into`} catch (\Exception $e)`. But you aren't returning a JSON response here, either. You're redirecting.

The issue is that the `redirect()` object does not contain a `->json()` method, but the `response()` object does. So change it:

```
return response()->json($items);
```

Also, in your error handler, return a `422` error code when responding, so it wil trigger the `.error()` on your promise.

```
return response(422)->json([$e->getMessage()]);
```

Comment: @CarlosOrtega Access the link directly in your browser. What happens?

Comment: `ReflectionException in Route.php line 333: Method App\Http\Controllers\backend\BillsController::show() does not exist` I got this

Comment: @CarlosOrtega A completely different issue. You are using  `resource controller routing` but you do not have all of the resourceful functions defined in your controller. Solve that.